# How to determine the dimensions of objects in an image using OpenCV and Python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have an image and I would like to extract the dimensions (width and height) along a red line drawn across the image. I want to measure the objects that intersect with this line.

To visualize the line, I have manually drawn a red line across the image, as shown here:
[image: Image with lines.]
Now, I need assistance on how to extract the dimensions of the objects intersecting this red line. Specifically, I would like to obtain the measurements in mm or any other relevant unit.

Could anyone please provide guidance, suggestions, or code examples on how to extract the dimensions along a red line in an image using OpenCV and Python?

I have already applied necessary preprocessing steps such as thresholding, contour detection, or any other relevant techniques.

I can only find the length and width of the image like this.
[image: Image Dimensions]

I appreciate any assistance or suggestions on how to approach this problem effectively.

Comment: Simply put, it is not possible.  How far were you from the object when the picture was taken?  What was the f-stop, focal length, and sensor size of the camera?  If you have all of these, then you can calculate the approximate size of the object.  Normally the dimension are calculate by placing the object on a mat with a grid with a known size before taking the picture.